# How get specific item from FacebookClient.get(me/feed) results

Tags: c#, facebook-c#-sdk

I want to retrieve the latest/last post and get only the message not the other junk info. From the below code spinet, i loop the the array and get the first element. How can i get only the message not the other information?

```
IDictionary<string, object> feed = fb.Get("me/feed") as dynamic;

JsonArray posts = feed.First().Value as dynamic;
```

I was able to do that in Java but i want the C# implementation.

```
Connection<Post> myFeed = fbclient.fetchConnection("me/feed", Post.class);
System.out.println("First item in my feed: " + myFeed.getData().get(0).getMessage());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your intention is to retrieve only the message of the latest post from the feed, then `fields=message&limit=1` is what you need to pass in the query string. Something like this:

```
dynamic feed = fb.Get("me/feed?fields=message&limit=1");
var latestMessage = feed[0][0].message;
```